# Group records using lookup object reference fields in fflib

Tags: apex, design-patterns, fflib

I have a use case to group the accounts with the DNB Company Records(lookup in account)'s Global_Ultimate_DUNS_Number__c and check if the accounts tied via Global DUNS if they are present in more than one country and employee count > 10000 set the Segmentation to "Global" else set it to "Enterprise".

Here's what I tried:

```
    IAccounts accountsWithGlobalDuns =  Accounts.newInstance(accountsWithGlobalDuns);

    Set<Id> dnbIds = globalDUNSAccounts.getDNBIds();

   // gives the dnbrecord id to global duns where dnbid is the id tied to the global ultimate account
    Map<Id, String> gdnbIdToGduns = DnBCompanyRecords.newInstance(
        DnBCompanyRecordsSelector.newInstance().selectById(dnbIds)
    ).getDNBIdByGDUNSWithDUNSSameAsGDUNS(); 

    //gives the dnbrecordid to its global duns association
    Map<Id, String> dnbIdToGduns = DnBCompanyRecords.newInstance(
        DnBCompanyRecordsSelector.newInstance().selectById(dnbIds)
    ).getDNBIdByGDUNS();

   //filters only the globalultimateaccounts
    IAccounts globalUtimateAccounts =  accountsWithGlobalDuns.selectByDNBId(gdnbIdToGduns.keySet());       
    
    Map<String, Decimal> gdunsByCountryCount = accountsWithGlobalDuns.getCountryCountByGDUNS(dnbIdToGduns)

    IAccounts globalUtimateAccountsInMoreThanOneCountry =  globalUtimateAccounts .selectByDnbIdAndGDUNSMoreThanCountryCount(
     1, dnbIdToGduns, gdunsByCountryCount 
    ).selectByEmployeesGreaterThan(10000).setSegmentation('Global');
```

Accounts:

```
selectByDnbIdAndGDUNSMoreThanCountryCount(Decimal countryCount, Map<Id, String> idToGDUNS, Map<String, Decimal> 
       gdundsToCount) {

for (Account account : getAccounts){

   if (gdundsToCount.get(idToGDUNS.get(account.Dnb_Company_Record__c)) > countryCount) {
                   // add 

      }

    return new Accounts(<list>);

 }
```

I feel like above is very complex. Is there any proper way to do this in fflib? Also, can we use directly use lookup field's reference in a domain class?

Comment: In general, the selector should just do the query, in your case, perhaps with an Aggregate query, then have a method that takes the selector results and refines it if the Aggregate query can't be used to deliver a final result. Your domain class issue should be posed as a separate question